# cv_bridge tutorial program (ROS node) not working

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a node using catkin work space after creating package the process of build is successful with following code .... but the problem is when I am running it using `rosrun cvtest image_converter.cpp` the run is successful but i am not getting the output. 
The **image_converter.cpp**  which suppose to subscribe **sensor_msgs** topic and convert the image to **opencv::mat** process the image and then display it back in ROS. To publish the message on **sensor_msgs** topic as the frame captured from kinect I am using `roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch`.
However I can see the image using `rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_color` which also subscribes the same topic sensor_msgs.

**Tried it with eclipse also but it is not working at all and unable to find the problem even in eclipse. its running there but no output.**

I am including the `roswtf` result also. (pls see after the code)

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
 
namespace enc = sensor_msgs::image_encodings;
 
static const char WINDOW[] = "Image window";
 
class ImageConverter
 {
   ros::NodeHandle nh_;
   image_transport::ImageTransport it_;
   image_transport::Subscriber image_sub_;
   image_transport::Publisher image_pub_;
   
public:
   ImageConverter()
     : it_(nh_)
   {
     image_pub_ = it_.advertise("out", 1);
     image_sub_ = it_.subscribe("in", 1, &ImageConverter::imageCb, this);
 
     cv::namedWindow(WINDOW);
   }
 
   ~ImageConverter()
   {
     cv::destroyWindow(WINDOW);
   }
 
   void imageCb(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
   {
     cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
     try
     {
       cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, enc::BGR8);
     }
     catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
     {
       ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
       return;
     }
 
     if (cv_ptr->image.rows > 60 && cv_ptr->image.cols > 60)
       cv::circle(cv_ptr->image, cv::Point(50, 50), 10, CV_RGB(255,0,0));
 
     cv::imshow(WINDOW, cv_ptr->image);
     cv::waitKey(3);
     
     image_pub_.publish(cv_ptr->toImageMsg());
   }
 };
 
 int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {
   ros::init(argc, argv, "image_converter");
   ImageConverter ic;
   ros::spin();
   return 0;
 }
```

Here is `roswtf` result

```
admin-pc@admin-pc:~/mywork$ roswtf
No package or stack in context
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

Found 2 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING You are missing core ROS Python modules: bloom -- rosrelease -- 
WARNING You are missing Debian packages for core ROS Python modules: bloom (python-bloom) -- rosrelease (python-rosrelease) -- 

================================================================================
Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
... done running graph rules

Online checks summary:

Found 1 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected:
 * /image_converter:
   * /in
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/124351/cv_bridge-tutorial-program-(ros-node)-not-working./) by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 205 on 2014-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to remap topic "in" of your converter to "/camera/rgb/image_color" (Output image of your camera). Try running it by:

```
rosrun cvtest image_converter.cpp in:=/camera/rgb/image_color
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2014-01-30**:
Thank you for your help, it worked finally.